# Does Angular CLI prevent timestamp update for *.TS files?

Tags: windows, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

After setting up an Angular 2 program using Angular CLI (following the procedure at https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) and using VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/) to work with the files I've noticed that the file timestamps for *.TS files do not get updated.  Testing on Windows 10, the problem occurs even if I make a change to a TS file with Notepad and do so immediately after reboot.  However, if I copy the TS files to another folder, they show updated timestamps.

When opening other folders, there is an instant display of files, but when opening the app folders with the TS files, there is a delay of several seconds, with a message "Working on it..."

The TS files had been associated with a video processing program ("transport stream" file), but I shifted the association to VS Code, but that didn't fix the problem.

I opened a bug report at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25569 but the VS Code folks could not reproduce the problem, suggesting that it is not seen for many VS Code users.  That report is now is some sort of limbo in which it is listed as closed but one can still comment.

So I'm wondering whether the Angular CLI environment prevents timestamp update for the TS files.

Any suggestions on how to get the TS files in an Angular 2 project to show the current timestamp?

Addendum: the problem is not just for ts files.  It extends to css files as well, as illustrated in this image in which the file system lists 19 April as the file date for styles.css, but the ToolTip for the file gives the more recent (correct) date:
[image: timestamp disagreement]

Clearly some part of this environment is overruling one of 2 displays of the file date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the timestamp; it is the column displayed in Windows Explorer.  Instead of the usual "Date Modified" column, "Date" was displayed. I don't think problem is caused by Angular CLI or VSCode. It looks like it is created by the video processing program ("transport stream") file type assignment; removing that file association and assigning *.ts to VSCode prevents the problem from occurring. However, this doesn't fix instances in which it occurred already; here is how to fix those:

In Windows Explorer click View on the menu, then "Add Columns". Uncheck "Date" and check "Date Modified".  You may want to remove "Length" as well.